# T-duality between $E_8 \times E_8$ and $\text{Spin(}32)/\mathbb{Z}_2$ heterotic strings at the $\sigma$-model level

Tags: string-theory, duality, sigma-models

I would like to understand how T-duality between the heterotic $E_8 \times E_8$ (HE) and heterotic $\textrm{Spin}(32)/\mathbb{Z}_2$ (HO) theories works, at the level of the worldsheet $\sigma$-model.

I had a look at Lubos Motl's answer to a related question: [T-Duality between Type HE String theory and Type HO string theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65092/t-duality-between-type-he-string-theory-and-type-ho-string-theory).

My question, stated differently, is: is it possible to understand this duality using something like Buscher rules? If yes, can someone point me to an appropriate reference where this is explained?

Comment: Have a look at http://inspirehep.net/record/231271 .

Comment: @Heterotic thanks! But this paper doesn't address T Duality from a sigma model perspective.